# Swift didSelectRowAt - A problem

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Я пытаюсь сменить цвет фона у ячейки таблицы. Код представлен ниже. Но при смене ячейки с indexPath = 0,1 цвет меняется у ячекк 0,1 И 0,11 И 0,21 И 0,31 и так далее, тоже самое если меняю цвет у 0,3 то меняется у 0,13 И 0,23 и так далее. Но сам indexPath верный - т е если вывести его print - то выдаст 0,1 и все! В чем может быть дело ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 104.0/255.0, green: 38.0/255.0, blue: 64.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)    
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит так как ячейки `reusable`. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно сбросить все настройки ячейки при ее создании.

```
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
```